# HTML5 Boilerplate Build Script - Directory Does not exist

Tags: html5boilerplate, build.xml

I'm trying to run the build script and encountering a BUILD FAILED message.  Something to do with the publish folder, specifically the images directory maybe.  The Error:

`Directory does not exist: /Users/lewis/Sites/slb-framework/publish/httpdocs/assets/img`

It seems as though its looking for a directory within the publish folder but the directory won't exist until script creates the publish folder as far as I can see.

I am using a different directory structure and have modified the project.properties to point to the correct sub-directories of the assets folder but it's failing right at the point where it starts the image compression.

I have jpegtran and optipng installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Your images folder needs to be as indicated in the HTML5 Boilerplate directory structure as far as I can tell. If it is still a problem please open an issue with the Github repo: https://github.com/h5bp/ant-build-script/issues